# Qt Display states according to country selected using models in qml

Tags: qt, qml, qabstractlistmodel

I want to display 2 listmodels. One is a list of countries and other one is the states in the selected country. What is the best way to do this. Iam using qml for the ui. All the data must be fetched from cpp and passed to qml.

My usecase is not exactly the same. But similar to this. Display another list corresponding to the data selected on another list.

Comment: Since you tagged the `QAbstractListModel`, does it imply you are using that? If so, you could write a hierarchical `QAbstractListModel` which can be easily bound to the second list

Comment: @Amfasis I tried creating 2 `QAbstractListModel` and a `QObject` class which consists of data to be passed to Model. For the first model i passed the `QObject` class directly. On clicking item in the model i invoke a method which returns correcponding object which i had given as the data to the second model. 
Now App is crashing trying to access the <not accessible> item.

Comment: Then I think you should "merge" the two. I find it a bit of a pain to write these hierarchical models, but I hope you can get there with this tutorial: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this using `QAbstractListModel`. It was the same use case i required. Always welcome if there is any better method than this. 
Attaching the link of a trial project here.

https://github.com/igokul95/country_state_city_selection